# nested push animation... after [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ] when returning from Add new item

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, scroll, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app has a method to add a new item to a table (using Core Data for storage) which initializes the new object, adds it to Core Data, and segues to an Edit view.

After editing and hitting the default "Back" button in the Edit view, I do the following in `ViewDidAppear` in order to scroll my table to the newly added item:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // if a new event was just added then scroll the tableview to it
    if (_newlyAddedEvent != nil) {
        [self.eventListTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_newlyAddedEventIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        _newlyAddedEvent = nil;
    }
    // dismiss the progress HUD
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

The code executes and throws the following two log messages:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
```

and

```
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

And of course, my navigation bar is all messed up.

`_newlyAddedEvent` is set in my `controllerDidChangeContent` method for the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

`_newlyAddedEventIndexPath = newIndexPath;` in the NSFetchedResultsController's `didChangeObject` method when `type = NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`.

Can anyone give me a hint what to look for to fix this?

I've tried adding `[self.eventListTable setDelaysContentTouches:NO];` in `ViewDidLoad` and it didn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in dispatch main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
^{
     [self.eventListTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_newlyAddedEventIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
 });
```